# Howto make $ known to one of my javascript dependencies in a typescript project

Tags: typescript

I am writing a typescript project (using vue.js) and want to use [lib-jitsi-meet](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet). I setup the project using vue cli. So I downloaded `lib-jitsi-meet-min.js` and placed it into my vendors folder.

I include it using:

```
import JitsiMeetJS from '@/vendors/lib-jitsi-meet.min'
```

It seems to work, I can call `JitsiMeetJS.init`.

But when I want to do more, as in calling other functions from JitsiMeetJs:

```
let connection = new JitsiMeetJS.JitsiConnection(null, null, options)
```

I get:

```
Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
```

So I need jquery.

I tried:

```
yarn add jquery
```

and include it like this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

But I still get the same error.
How do I import/add jquery in my project so that it can be used by lib-meet-jitsi?

Comment: What is the "more" you are doing?

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie Good point, sorry for being so unclear, I edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/12/external-javascript-dependencies-in-typescript-and-angular-2

I do this:

```
// Import jquery
import * as $ from 'jquery'
// Import my library, that needs #
import JitsiMeetJS from '@/vendors/lib-jitsi-meet.min'
// Extend the window type with globals for jquery
declare global {
 interface Window {
    $: any;
    jQuery: any;
  }
}
// Set the globals
window.$ = $
window.jQuery = $
```

And it works!

Comment: While this is correct answer, I'd argue it might not be the correct approach. It seems like a total overkill to add a large dependency like jQuery into your project because of a single package. If I were you I'd rather re-condsider different package for what you're trying to achieve that doesn't require jQuery.

There's a reason why jQuery has been steadily declining in popularity due to rising favour of frameworks/libraries like React or Vue. Fusing them together, seems like a total overkill